# Observer reporting to multiple layers up from the bottom of hierarchy

Tags: design-patterns, python, programming-practices, gui

There is a `swarm` of objects. When a new `unit` of certain kind appears on the frame, the `swarm` integrates this object by calling some `add_new_unit` method. Above the `swarm` is a `controller` abstraction, which handles multiple swarms of different types and the interaction with an image processing abstraction that detects units on the frame. Above the `controller` is a `GUI` layer.

I want to add a new widget to the `GUI` every time a new `unit` is added to the `swarm`. Essentially, I need to call some method of `GUI` abstraction object from the `swarm`, but there is the `controller` object in the hierarchy between them. Moreover, I want to be able to update this widget when some methods of `unit` are called (i.e. move the position of the widget together with `unit`'s position)

Going top-to-bottom: `GUI` knows only about `controller`, `controller` knows only about `swarm` and `swarm` knows only about its `units`. I tried to decouple everything as much as possible and isolate every layer. Basically now I am trying to make a way to communicate the information from the bottom (from a `unit`, i. e. its position, speed and other status parameters) all the way to the top, when some events on a `unit` or `swarm` levels happen. I want to keep `controller` independent of `GUI` as much as possible.

Is there a way to achieve the above-stated goal without coupling objects from the bottom to the top - i. e. without letting a `unit` know about a `swarm`, or without letting a `controller` know about `GUI`?

I am thinking about Observer that will report to `controller`, which fires some handler method every time it observes `add_new_unit` of the `swarm` called. But in this case do I need to create Observer that will report to `GUI`, that will observe `controller``s observer? Something tells me there should be a way to do that which does not involve so much redundancy.

The language in question is Python 3.7

Here is some code to demonstrate - I want `GUI.add_new_widget_for_unit` to be called every time `Swarm.add_new_unit` is called, and later modify that widget when some methods of `Unit` are called:

```
class Unit:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Swarm:
    def __init__(self):
        self.units = []

    def update(self, units):
        """
        Some updating/tracking logic here...
        """
        if new_units_on_image:
             new_unit = Unit(*params)
             self.add_new_unit(new_unit)

    def add_new_unit(self, unit)
        self.units.append(unit)

class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.swarm = Swarm()
        self.image_processing = ImageProcessing()

    def update(self):
        units_on_image = self.image_processing.update()
        self.swarm.update(units_on_image)

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.controller = Controller()

    def update(self):
        """ 
        Gets updated by some timer
        """
        self.controller.update()

    def add_new_widget_for_unit(self, parameters_of_unit):
        """
        Adding widget with certain parameters from the unit
        """
```

Comment: Give us some idea what architecture you're using now. You name many different components. Which ones know about each other?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Edited the question, hope it will bring some clarification. I have been reading about various patterns and design principles, but struggle to figure out the solution in practice. I think there is no need to say I'm a very beginner. Also have no people around me who know anything related to programming so ANY advice is very welcome!

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "nice," "good," "right" and "better"
 (without resorting to tautologies like "best practice").

Comment: Thanks for your comment, hope now it's better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the generic Observer as suggested by the other answer. But consider this:

> Going top-to-bottom: GUI knows only about controller, controller knows only about swarm and swarm knows only about its units. I tried to decouple everything as much as possible and isolate every layer

and

> I want to add a new widget to the GUI every time a new unit is added to the swarm

You suggested design and your requirement are not well aligned. You don't have a generic use case, only a single specific one. You could decide some nuances, like for example when to signal your observers, according to this specific case. There is still de facto coupling between your layers, and there will be until you have several front-ends.

So it is not that strict to use the generic Observer pattern at all layers. You could instead - and when there are details of implementation required by the specific case it may even be desirable - inject the specific callback "addGuiWidget", or reference to some GUI-level object which would add the widget. In a statically typed language you would have to introduce interface for injecting an object, but for python even that is not necessary.

PS: "inject the specific callback" looks approximately like (I could make some mistake in python syntax):

```
class Unit:
    def set_add_widget_callback(self, callback):
        self.add_widget_callback = callback

    def add_widget(self):
        assert(self.add_widget_callback is not None)
        self.add_widget_callback(self.foo) # passing parameters

class Swarm:
    def set_add_widget_callback(self, callback):
        self.swarm.add_widget_callback = callback

    def add_new_unit(self, unit)
        unit.set_add_widget_callback(self.add_widget_callback)
        ...

class Controller:
    def set_add_widget_callback(self, callback):
        self.swarm.set_add_widget_callback(callback)

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.controller = Controller()
        self.controller.set_add_widget_callback(self.add_new_widget_for_unit)
```

PS2:

> Moreover, I want to be able to update this widget when some methods of unit are called (i.e. move the position of the widget together with unit's position)

Now it looks like you rather should pass the reference to the GUI object. Or you could make an simplified adapter of it.

Comment: I don't completely understand what exactly you mean by "inject the specific callback". I have added some code for the demonstration. Could you please point to where I should add this callback?

Comment: I have also added an additional requirement to the question - I want to be able to modify the created widget when some methods of `Unit` are called. Should I still be just adding callbacks?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the **Observer pattern.**  Your top layers should be able to subscribe to events exposed by the lower layers.  Then the lower layers can provide notification, send messages or transmit data by firing events.  The lower layers will have no idea who they're talking to.

[This article](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Observer.html) describes a method involving translating Java's Observable's objects to Python.  Anecdotally, this seems like overkill.  You ought to be able to simply hand your lower-level object a higher-order function that it can call to notify the upper layer.

You can also try the [Command Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command/python/1).

Comment: What puts me off in the pattern from the article about the Observer pattern that you have linked is that I will have to write somewhere in the code a construct like `controller.swarm.add_new_unit`, meaning that (as far as I understand it) I have to create an Observer instance in the top `GUI` object, and to assign it to observe the object two layers below I will inevitably couple `GUI` to `swarm`, not just `GUI` to `controller` and `controller` to `swarm`. I am not sure, but I thought that kind of coupling should be avoided?

Comment: That's why I think your lower-level object could expose an endpoint that accepts a first-class method delegate.  Your higher-lebel object can plug into this endpoint.

Comment: Have a look here: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Delegates#Python

Comment: @RobertHarvey it seems to be very overcomplicated, any [callable object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-32) such as instance method reference or lambda should be enough.

Comment: @max630: Yes, that should indeed be enough.

Comment: I have edited the question to add the code and additional requirement that might be important in this case - "I want to be able to update this widget when some methods of unit are called (i.e. move the position of the widget together with unit's position)"